# Generics in recursive method

Tags: java, generics, recursion, nested-generics

I've been banging my head on the table over this for a few hours now.

I have this Map:
`private static Map<Class<? extends BaseClass>, Predicate<? extends BaseClass>> constraints;`

And I have this method:

```
public static <C extends BaseClass> Predicate<C> getConstraints(Class<? super C> clazz) {
    if (clazz == BaseClass.class) {
        return (Predicate<C>) constraints.getOrDefault(BaseClass.class, x -> true);
    }
    Class<? super C> superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
    return constraints.getOrDefault(clazz, x -> true).and(getConstraints(superClass));
}
```

All this is supposed to do is to chain all constraints for a certain class (and the superclasses) in a `Predicate<T>` using the `and()` method.
The generics seem logical to me but I still get an error when making the recursive call. `getConstraints(Class<? super C>) cannot be applied to Class<capture of ? super E>`. I don't get it because `superClass` is of the type `Class<? super C>` which is exactly the parameter that my method accepts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a type variable that represents the superclass:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <S extends BaseClass, C extends S> Predicate<C> getConstraints(Class<C> clazz) {
    if (clazz == BaseClass.class) {
        return (Predicate<C>) constraints.getOrDefault(BaseClass.class, x -> true);
    }
    Class<S> superClass = (Class<S>) clazz.getSuperclass();
    Predicate<C> p1 = (Predicate<C>) constraints.getOrDefault(clazz, x -> true);
    Predicate<S> p2 = getConstraints(superClass);
    return p1.and(p2);
}
```

You will also have to cast the result of `getOrDefault`, since putting the `Predicate` in the map 'forgets' the type information, and you get back a generic `Predicate<? extends BaseClass>`, which you can't use directly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that work's great. I've discovered the parameter `C` can be omitted. The parameter `S` is enough.